# Reloading Images On Page Reload

Tags: php, html, image, reload

I have a button that reloads the page:

```
<input type="button" name="reloadPage" id="reloadPage" value="Refresh Data" onclick="location.href = '<?=$Domain?>unitstatus.php";/>
```

But all of the .gif images on the page do not reload. Is there any way to make them reload when the button is clicked?

```
<img src="images/10frame.gif";>
```

The above is the image that doesn't reload when the page reloads. The .gif image stays at the last frame and does not start at the beginning frame.

Comment: Your script uploads new gif image and it is not updated after refresh?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"the .gif images on the page do not reload"*?  Show us a JSFiddle, please

Comment: @SeanDoe The .gif images that are on the page stay at the last frame and do not start from the first frame. To explain, the gif images show that data is being sent, and when the gif is done, it displays a check mark as the last frame.

Comment: @Madbreaks Sorry for not being more specific, see my above comment.

Comment: Please include more of your code. What gifs are you talking about?

Comment: @Robbert I added an example to what the image would be. The .gif, when I click the button, stays at the last frame and doesn't start at the beginning frame.

Comment: I assume this is an animated gif and when the page loads, the gif doesn't start from the beginning. Try adding a random number to the end of the src: i.e. `<img src="images/10frame.gif?<?PHP echo uniqid; ?>">`.  This will circumvent browser caching of images.

Comment: ^ Exactly what I had in mind. Check out my answer.

Comment: @Robbert This makes the image not load at all, I assume because the unique number at the end is not the exact file name of the image.

Comment: Did you put the question mark after `.gif`?

Comment: @Robbert whoops. Now it is there, but still doesn't start from the beginning frame. It is still at the ending frame.

Comment: Are you sure the page is reloading?

Comment: @Robbert Confirmed that the button reloads the page.

Comment: I wrote the code for what I think @robbert here is trying to say.

Comment: @EisaAdil I am currently implementing your code to see if it works. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Robbert uniqid; needed to be uniqid(); That solved my issue. Thank you all SOOOOO much for the help!!!

Comment: @EisaAdil uniqid; needed to be uniqid(); That solved my issue. Thank you all SOOOOO much for the help!!!

Comment: Yay! Thanks for the +1 though.

Comment: @EisaAdil You deserved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer above works, but is overly complex.  Just using this code will resolve the issue

```
<img src="images/10frame.gif?<?PHP echo uniqid(); ?>">
```

This will add a querystring to the end of the url for the image and bypass any caching by the browser.

Comment: But how does this work on the click of a button? I mean, you'd need to use AJAX, right?

Comment: The button reloads the page. Everytime the page reloads, the image needs to be reloaded bypassing browser cache.

Comment: Just great! This was the first thing that came to my mind when I was think about a solution for this. I thought we couldn't reload the page. THAT's why I wrote the JS code. Haha. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" name="reloadPage" id="reloadPage" value="Refresh Data"/>

<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
    $('img').attr('href') = img.attr('href') + '?' + unix; //put question mark after the img links and after that writes a unique number
});
</script>
```

The above code should change the href link to a dynamic one. That is `img/10frame.png` would become `img/10frame.png?2002344`.

As Robbert said -

> This will circumvent browser caching of images.